# How to extract boot.img from two ".bin" files (TF Flash Image)

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, ota-update, images, magisk

I have got a TF Card flash image for my Hisense A6 (`HLTE700T`) and is trying to extract boot.img from it.

However, instead of payload.bin, two bin files are present in the zip file:

```
HLTE700T_TF (folder)
-- HLTE700T.bin (3.59GB)
-- HLTE700T_1.bin (1.00GB)
```

Those boot.img extract tools only accept one input and fails to extract the files. How can I extract boot.img?

Here's the TF card flash image if needed: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V921UTZxVGbwiQpVNmrmC1DYTpVf3hfj/view?usp=sharing) (Link UPDATED)

Comment: `file` says SysEx File (JEN) unknown file format. maybe it's easier to dump boot.img off device itself? I recommend python script [edl.py](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) (*xxx.prog_emmc_ufs_firehose_Sdm660_ddr.elf* can be downloaded [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3932041) 1st link) your upload is corrupt btw don't use it

Comment: The link is updated and the uploaded file is no longer corrupt.

Comment: Extracting with QFIL worked well for me. Thanks for @alecxs 's advice!